# I worked on a tutorial application and I followed a guide to host it on gh-pages. Why is the routing messed up now?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, github-pages, angular-cli-ghpages

Source code for app: https://github.com/shardul-shah/first-angular-app

It works on gh-pages... kind of (https://shardul-shah.github.io/first-angular-app/)

Problems:

1. When going to this, https://shardul-shah.github.io/first-angular-app/ , the URL automatically changes to https://shardul-shah.github.io/first-angular-app/first-angular-app/
2. Refresh of https://shardul-shah.github.io/first-angular-app/first-angular-app/ (or any refresh for that matter on any route) leads to white, empty screen.
3. The app works when I click "my store" in https://shardul-shah.github.io/first-angular-app/first-angular-app/ , but not without that.

I saw the JS console, and I see I am getting problems with the route as well. I can see there are problems with the routing, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix it. I already tried 4 times to rebuild and reserve using ng and ng's gh-pages command line utility, but it didn't fix it. My inexperience with Angular and routing in it is hurting.

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this routing so the app behaves like normal and works from https://shardul-shah.github.io/first-angular-app/ ?

FYI, it works on stackblitz, where I originally worked on the app:
https://angular-n2rqei.stackblitz.io and https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n2rqei?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Thanks!
[image: GitHub settings (pages)]

Comment: Can you please show me a screenshot of root directory in settings from where you set your build as a root folder for GH-pages.

Comment: Done. Sorry for the delay, on mobile right now.

Comment: Please don't link to source code. [Edit] your question and add it here as a [mcve]. Links can break, or the code pointed to can change, making the question useless for others with the same problem. See also [ask].

Comment: @Robert I will do so today, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solutions :
**Solution for 1st problem :**

1. You might add one more folder in src/index.html in base. that's why it is load all routes after this url. (check screenshot) [Use ./ in base instead of github folder or anything else]

[image]

### **Solution for 2nd Problem :**

1. Refresh on any routes gets page blank white screen. it's because of you are not using useHashStretegy in your angular.
2. You have to use useHash stretegy in your angular application like :

   ```
   RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
   ```

In your case like this :

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '', component: ProductListComponent },
  { path: 'products/:productId', component: ProductDetailsComponent },
  { path: 'cart', component: CartComponent },
  { path: 'shipping', component: ShippingComponent }
], { useHash: true })
```

**Note :** If you don't want Hash(#) in your url, then you have to setup `.htaccess` file that can redirect(Rewrite URL) all request into angular build's index.html file. but that is not allows by github so  you have to use dedicated server for that. More info about rewrite rule is here : [server configuration](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration)

More info about it on this link : https://medium.com/@dao.houssene/angular-the-hash-trap-b2d415c2c241

### **solution for 3rd problem**

I hope so if your first two problem will fix then third will be automatically fixed.

### **Note:**

I have also setup this kind of page on github using angular. you can checkout my code and repo. form this package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/rotate-control

Comment: Hi Mayur,

I did the change you suggested, but now the page won't load itself: https://shardul-shah.github.io/first-angular-app/.

What can I do for #1 now?

Comment: Hi, have you use hashstrategy in your code? I have check app module but not found any stretegy so asking.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Please use <base href="./">  (Dot-slash instead of only slash in base in index file)

Comment: After doing what you said Mayur, the page works, and I believe the refreshing problem (#2) and #3 also got fixed!

Can you please explain why changing the base href to "first-angular-app" to "./" fixed the problem please?

I still don't understand. I accepted your answer + upvoted as it helped me, thanks Mayur!

Comment: Base Url is used by router to find files which has relative url. Means if your js file contain relative path like `/js/xyz.js`, then how angular know that from where, I have to search for this file. that's why base href is prepended on relative path.

More info about `base href` is here : https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-base-href-in-angular-2